# Laravel Search between two numbers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I currently have the following function in my search controller. I also want to retrieve the results where the space_price is between the user min and max input.  I also want the query to work if the user doesn't enter a min or max value or if they enter a max value and no min value it will return the results between 0 and the max value.

```
$town = $_GET['town'];
$category = $_GET['category'];
$min = $_GET['min'];
$max = $_GET['max'];

$spaces = \App\Space::where([ 
    ['space_town', 'LIKE', '%' . $town . '%'],
    ['space_category', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%'],
])->get();

return view('search', compact('spaces'));
```

Thanks in advance,
Jamie

Comment: You should dynamically append to the query... Not familiar with laravel, should `$town` and `$category` be placeholders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to use PHP condition to check whether the max and min value is given or not. So the final code will look like this:

```
$town = $_GET['town'];
$category = $_GET['category'];
$min = empty($request->input('min')) ? 0 : $request->input('min');
$max = empty($request->input('max')) ? 0 : $request->input('max');

$query = \App\Space::where([ 
['space_town', 'LIKE', '%' . $town . '%'],
['space_category', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%'],]);

// check if any of max or min value is given

if($min!=0 || $max!=0 ){
 $query = $query->whereBetween('space_price', array($min, $max)); 
}

$spaces = $query->get(); 

return view('search', compact('spaces'));
```

Answer (score 1):

So first when you use Laravel don't use the GET parameters directly instead call them over the framework.

```
$min = $request->input('min');
```

So you don't fight the framework and work with that functions for security reasons.

So when you need a default value you can define a value with the short hand operator or with an if statement.

With your query use `>` and `<` in your query. So append that fields to your array and define which field should be bigger and which field should be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like **whereBetween()**.

```
$spaces = \App\Space::where(['space_town', 'LIKE', '%' . $town . '%'],
    ->whereBetween('price', [$min_price, $max_price])
    ->get();
```

In every case you will be sending `min_price` and `max_price` if user is not selecting any value you will be posting default values anyhow. so that it fetches result within that values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel `5.7.19` and higher

by default laravel Ships with the function named as `whereBetween`

it will work on the collection

I have referred to the post @ `https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-19`

```
$c = new Collection([
    ['v' => 1], 
    ['v' => 2], 
    ['v' => 3], 
    ['v' => '3'], 
    ['v' => 4]
]);

$this->assertEquals(
    [
        ['v' => 2],
        ['v' => 3],
        ['v' => '3'],
        ['v' => 4]
    ],
    $c->whereBetween('v', [2, 4])->values()->all()
);
```

for Full article kindly 
[https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-19][ClickHere]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set max and min value as 0 the use MySQL between. If the user does not put min max value the it will searched as default value 0

SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN 10 AND 20